# Data Conversion

Tags: sql

How do I convert 0.50 to 50 or 0.1429 to 14.29 in sql query?
My data type is real.

Comment: select case when value = 0.50 then 50 else when value = 0.1429 then 14.29 end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by `100`.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply it by 100. : )

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but it's like this:

`Select 0.50 *100 as MyNewNumber`

or

`Select MyColumn *100 as MyNewNumber`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (column * 100) FROM TABLE
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 0.50*100
```

in sort

```
SELECT (data * 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.`value`*100 FROM invoice
```